# In reCAPTCHA, what data is being sent to Google and how often?

Tags: recaptcha, captcha

In other words:

- When Google is trying to determine whether it's a real user or not (for invisible captcha), which data is collected and how often is it sent to Google?
- Which user events are being captured?
- Is Google collecting any other data which is not relevant to user behavior for captcha purposes?

Thanks

Comment: I found some great info here: https://termsfeed.com/blog/privacy-policy-recaptcha/

But I still would like to know from the community, specially from these who have any experience with this.